# Как определить IP адрес?

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, как написать или с чего начать. Короче, есть два компа. На одном динамический ip (клиент) на другом статический ip (сервер). Необходимо, что бы ip клиента отображался на сервере. Клиент выходит на сервер через интернет поэтому нужен внешний IP адрес.

Comment: Компоненты клиента и сервера в студию (названия) + код приема запроса от клиента на сервере.

Comment: Что такое сервер и клиент? Если они соединяются по tcp (в том числе по http), то в структуре sockaddr при вызове accept запоминается адрес клиента. Как получить эти данные в delphi, я не знаю. Но они там есть :)

Answer (score 3):

Когда-то решал подобную задачу. Есть такие компоненты, как idhttp(клиент) и idhttpserver(сервер). Нужно сделать запрос клиентом к серверу. При этом на событие получения запроса сервером выставить извлечение ip адреса клиента.

Событие - `OnCommandGet`

```
procedure TForm2.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);

begin

memo1.Lines.Add(arequestinfo.RemoteIP);


end;
```

В результате в мемо появится айпишник клиента, выполнившего запрос на сервер

На стороне клиента нужно функцией `idhttp1.GET('http://айпиадрессервера')` сделать запрос (предварительно установив на форму компонент idhttp, и выставив `idhttp1.GET('http://айпиадрессервера')` скажем, на нажатие кнопки.

Answer (score -1):

```
function LocalIP: String;
type
  TaPInAddr = Array[0..10] of PInAddr;
  PaPInAddr = ^TaPInAddr;
var
  phe: PHostEnt;
  pptr: PaPInAddr;
  Buffer: Array[0..63] of Char;
  I: Integer;
  GInitData: TWSAData;
begin
  WSAStartup($101, GInitData);
  Result := '';
  GetHostName(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer));
  phe := GetHostByName(buffer);
  if phe = nil then Exit;
  pPtr := PaPInAddr(phe^.h_addr_list);
  I := 0;
  while pPtr^[I] <> nil do
   begin
    Result := inet_ntoa(pptr^[I]^);
    Inc(I);
   end;
  WSACleanup;
end;
```

Comment: Вопрос был не про этот адрес, а про адрес клиента на сервере

Answer (score -2):

На клиенте получать свой IP и передавать его серверу.
От того, какой IP нужен, внешний или внутренний, можно использовать `TCPipClient` или парсить `internet.yandex.ru`.